# Who have I blocked on GChat?

Tags: google-talk

Recently I found out I'd accidentally blocked someone on GChat, and now I'd like to know who else I might have blocked?

How do I figure this out? (I have too many contacts to go through them one by one.)

Comment: What in the world was the point of closing this question 4 years after it was validly posted and already answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gmail Chat, as I'm sure you know, you can block or unblock anyone by typing their names into the chat box, hovering over and selecting or deselecting **Block PersonX**. However, this requires that you know who it is you're trying to unblock.

The best solution I've found for viewing a list of who you have blocked is this [workaround](http://www.renjusblog.com/2009/12/gmail-view-blocked-contacts-unblock.html) wherein you install and run Google Talk using your Gmail address. From there you can go to **Settings >> Blocked**. The "Blocked" section will show you a list of everyone you have blocked and you can block or unblock them individually or in bulk. This *should* sync back with your Gmail chat, but if not you will at lease know which contacts you want to unblock and can do so using the first method I described (also [described here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/gmail/ab3EASBuB8k) in the Google product forum.)